# Prove $u'(t)= \lambda u(t)$ has only one unique solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let for $a \in \mathbb{R} \quad$ $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto a\cdot x $ be continuous and let $u_0$ be an intial value in $\mathbb{R}$.

I showed that if $u\in C^1([0,\infty])$ satisfies

$$ \begin{cases}
  u'(t) = f(u(t))\\    
  u(0) = u_0   
\end{cases} $$

that it is equivalent to the claim that

$$u(t)=u_0+ \int_0^t f(u(s)) ds$$
which was part of the exercise.
Now I only want to show that there exists exactly one solution $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}_+)$ that satisfies above properties.

I think it's $u(t)=u_0\cdot e^{at}$. **Now I need to show that it is unique.** I tried claiming there is a second one and then showing $u(t)=g(t)$ for all $t$ using only the properties above but I didn't make a lot of progress. **What is a good approach to showing it is unique?**

Note: I don't have any background in differential equations if this is one ( this is part of a calculus course )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the product rule to show that the derivative of $g(t) = e^{-at}u(t)$ is zero, and the mean value theorem implies that a function with derivative equal to zero is constant. (This constant is of course uniquely determined by the initial condition.)